# Injection of Golang environment variables into Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, go, pipeline, cicd

I am currently migrating some build components to *Azure Pipelines* and am attempting to set some environment variables for all Golang related processes. I wish to execute the following command within the pipeline:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build [...]
```

When utilizing the provided *Golang* integrations, it is easy to add arguments for *Go* related processes, but setting an environment variable for all (or for every individual) *Go* process does not seem possible. Neither *[GoTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/go-tool-v0?view=azure-pipelines)* or the default *[Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/go-v0?view=azure-pipelines)* task seem to support it, and performing a *[script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-script?view=azure-pipelines)* task with a shell execution in it do not seem to be supported either.

I have also tried adding an environment variable to the entire pipelines process that defines the desired flags, but these appear to be ignored by the *Go* task provided by Azure Pipelines itself.

Would there be a way to do add these flags to each (or a single) go process, such as how I do it in the following code block (in which the *flags* input line was made-up by me)?

```
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    flags: 'CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64'
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '[...]'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Build the application'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information I was able to find and many hours of debugging, I ended up using a workaround in which I ran the `golang` commands in a `CmdLine@2` task, instead. Due to how `GoTool@0` sets up the pipeline and environment, this is possible.

Thus, the code snippet below worked for my purposes.

```
steps: 
- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.19.0'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```